# $P\sin(\alpha)$ and not $\sin(\alpha)/P$?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, forces, friction

Why is the force parallel to the surface that pushes the object $P \sin(\alpha)$ and not $\frac{\sin(\alpha)}{P}$?
I didn't understand when they showed me it. can someone give me an answer in full detail?

[image: Sketch]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've redrawn the relevant bit of your diagram to make it clearer:

[image: Forces]

The force due to gravity, $P = mg$, obviously points straight down. Any force can be drawn as the vector sum of other forces, and in this case it's convenient to draw it as the vector sum of the force parallel to the plane, $F_p$, and the force normal to the plane, $F_n$. So in the diagram the three lines labelled $P$, $F_p$ and $F_n$ form a right angled triangle with the angle between $P$ and $F_n$ being $\alpha$.

Basic trigonometry then tells us that:

$$ F_n = P \cos \alpha $$

$$ F_p = P \sin \alpha $$

Comment: Thanks. I found few answers. but yours seems to be the most simplest.

Answer (score 3):

First, the normal force in the picture is pointing in the wrong direction.

Second, a force cannot be $\frac{sin(\alpha)}{P}$ when $P$ is a force, since it would have the units of $\frac{1}{N}$. Moreover, if $P$ gets bigger, the total net force should get bigger, too, which is not the case if you have $P$ in the denominator.

If you change the direction of $\vec{N}$ and attach its starting point to the endpoint of $\vec{P}$, then you get a right-angled triangle with the third side being the total net force, $\vec{F}$ in this case. The angle between the vectors $\vec{P}$ and $\vec{N}$ is $\alpha$. If we take the geometric properties of $sin$, we get

$$sin(\alpha) = \frac{\text{opposite leg}}{\text{hypotenuse}} = \frac{\left|\vec{F}\right|}{\left|\vec{P}\right|} \Rightarrow \left|\vec{F}\right| = \left|\vec{P}\right| \cdot sin(\alpha)$$

Answer (score 3):

A. Dimensional analysis.

The force should have the dimensions $M^1L^1T^{-2}$ (Newton). $\frac{\sin(\alpha)}{P}$ has the dimensions $M^{-1}L^{-1}T^{2}$, or $\frac{1}{Newton}$

B. Geometry.

If you've understood how the angle between the downward force and its component normal to the surface is $\alpha$, consider this:

The force component in the direction of the incline is opposite to the angle $\alpha$ in that particular right-angled triangle.

We know that $\frac{opposite}{hypotenuse} = \sin(\alpha)$

i.e. $\frac{P}{F} = \sin(\alpha) $, or $P = F \times \sin(\alpha)$